# How can I determine what "inline script" Firefox console is complaining about regarding my Content Security Policy?

Tags: security, firefox

I set up a Content Security Policy and Chrome is perfectly happy with it.  Firefox though displays these errors in the console.

These line numbers do not point to script (e.g. 1:1 is just `<!DOCTYPE html>`).

How can I determine what script Firefox is complaining about?

```
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“script-src”). xxx.com:1:1    
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“script-src”). xxx.com:3:4629
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a [NoScript](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/noscript/)  issue. Tell NoScript to allow scripts.

It is related to where the document lives and apparently has nothing to do with the document's content.

I can reproduce the issue on my local filesystem (`file:///tmp/test.html`) with this tiny HTML snippet:

```html
<html><head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
</head><body>test</body>
</html>
```

<sup>(Note the lack of scripts. The `<meta>` tag only exists to suppress the character encoding complaint.)</sup>

When I tell NoScript to allow scripts from `file:` and refresh the page, the policy notice goes away.